# I want to create multiple pdfs in a loop using dompdf?

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation

I want to generate multiple pdf files in loop using dompdf. I am using dompdf_0-6-0_beta3. But only one file get generated each time wehn I execute the code. I am providing my code for reference as follows.

```
include 'dompdf_config.inc.php';

for($i=0; $i<5; $i++)
{
  if ( get_magic_quotes_gpc() )


  $old_limit = ini_set("memory_limit", "16M");

  $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
  $dompdf->load_html($i);
  $dompdf->set_paper('a4', 'portrait');
  $dompdf->render();

  $dompdf->stream($i.".pdf");
 }
```

So please help me in this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'l have to save your all PDFs to server and then redirect User to download these PDFs.

```
include 'dompdf_config.inc.php';

$file_to_save = '/path/to/your/public_html/pdf/';

for($i=0; $i<5; $i++)
{
  if ( get_magic_quotes_gpc() )
      $old_limit = ini_set("memory_limit", "16M");

  $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
  $dompdf->load_html($i);
  $dompdf->set_paper('a4', 'portrait');
  $dompdf->render();

  //Save PDF in server.
  file_put_contents($file_to_save."file".$i.".pdf", $dompdf->output()); 

 } 

 //open popup window to download all PDFs to client browser.
 echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
 for($i=0;$i<5: $i++){
      echo "window.open('/pdf/file{$i}.pdf');" ;
 }
 echo "</script>";
```

Comment: Hi Ravi , do you have any idea about how to give option to user to save downloaded file as per his directory structure ?

Comment: As per his directory structure means? 
I gave you example of opening popup window, instead you can "echo" individual links to download files!

Comment: Means I want to give user option to choose where to store pdf files after clicking Generate PDf link

Comment: Means , I want to add $file_to_save link updated as per clients machine...just link file save dialog..