# save multiple pdf files using dompdf in loop not working

Tags: php, dompdf

I am using dompdf. I want to save multiple pdf files to the server. Below is my code through which im trying to accomplish this task. But im getting all my orders in one pdf file. That means only one pdf file is generated although the loop is executing more than once. And the data is appending in the same pdf file and also the data is correct.

```
$sel_orders = "SELECT * FROM tbl_orders WHERE `user_id`=$user_id AND `mail`='pending' GROUP BY order_num";
$order_res = mysql_query($sel_orders);
$sum = mysql_num_rows($order_res);

$dir = dirname(__FILE__);
require_once($dir.'/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php');
if($sum > 0)
{
    while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($order_res))
    {
        $order_num = $row1['order_num']; // test-123
        $post = new stdClass;
        ob_start();
        include($dir.'/pdf.php');
        $pdf_html = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        $dompdf = new DOMPDF(); // Create new instance of dompdf
        $dompdf->load_html($pdf_html); // Load the html
        $dompdf->render(); // Parse the html, convert to PDF
        $pdf_content = $dompdf->output(); // Put contents of pdf into variable for later
        error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);     
        $file_to_save = '"http://www.exampe.com/test/orders/$order_num.pdf"';
        file_put_contents($file_to_save, $dompdf->output());        

    }
}
```

In pdf.php file I have my html code which is printed in pdf created. Each time the control enters the loop I want to create one separate pdf. I tried the solution from below link but it doesnt work for me. Someone plz point me what im doing wrong?? If any further info needed plz let me know. Thanks!

[I want to create multiple pdfs in a loop using dompdf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22370649/i-want-to-create-multiple-pdfs-in-a-loop-using-dompdf)

Comment: Are you able to open the PDF with all the orders? Are you sure the loop is running more than once? Because if the loop is running more than once you should only get the last PDF rendered.

Comment: Also, in your sample code `$file_to_save` has single then double quotes meaning the file name will not generate as you expect.

Comment: @BrianS Dear you are right, the loop was not running more than once. Actually the resultset variable in pdf.php was conflicting the resultset variable in my actual code file. Moreover I am calling this files from my swift project therefore it was hard time to me to test. Now it is resolved many thanks for your given tips!

Answer (score 0):

I very much doubt a web site is going to let you save a file to it using a URL, either way its easier to use a relative path and filename, even if this is your site where the code is running.

Start by using a real and valid filename for the output. Also you save the document into `$pdf_content` and then dont use that variable.

```
$pdf_content = $dompdf->output(); 

// make this a valid directory and filename for your site
// check that the web server account has correct privilages to write to it
$file_to_save = "/test/orders/$order_num.pdf";

file_put_contents($file_to_save, $pdf_content);
```

Comment: Dear I have used the relative path and tested, it was not working therefore I have used the URL path. And if there is write permissions issue then even one file should not be created I hope. Anyways the problem seems to be with pdf.php file. Let me modify pdf.php file and make few tests then ill get back again if the issue continues to exist. Thanks!